# Tomcat doesn't serve static files outside application server

Tags: java, tomcat

I want to be able to access files on my system that are outside the application server.

I have added this line on the server.xml under host tag:

```
<Context  docBase="/home/user/uploads" path="/files" />
```

On my jsp, I have

```
<a href="/files/${document.name}" class="thumbnail">
```

I keep getting 404 on the url:
http://localhost:8080/files/filename

Any idea?

Comment: Who is tomcat running as? Does that user have access to those files? P.S. this is quite a dangerous idea...

Comment: Yeah, the user has access to these files. This is a personal small project, no worries about the security. @BoristheSpider

Comment: Does `/home/user/uploads/WEB-INF/web.xml` exist and it's valid? Could you check the catalina.log and make sure the **WAR** is started?

Comment: @beckyang `web.xml` is not required. Neither is a war file.